# Alignment of components in a gui window

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, layout-manager

I have got a window that looks like window1 and I would like it to look like window2:

[image]

This is my code:

```
    String q = "Have you used GUI before?";     
    JLabel textLabel2 = new JLabel(
        "<html><div style=\"text-align: center;\">" + q + "</html>", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    add(textLabel2, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JPanel radioPanel = new JPanel();                                           
    add(radioPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
    add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

For the radio-buttons, I tried to use GridLayout, but it broke the position of "Yes" and "No". And for the "back" and "next" buttons, horizontal alignment did not work (`btnPanel.setAlignmentX(RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);`), apparently. Any solutions will be highly appreciated, I'm stuck with this bit way too long. Thanks

**--EDIT--**
  That is working perfectly fine:

```
btnPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(btnPanel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
btnPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 10, 10, 10));
btnPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
```

so the buttons problem is solved.
  However, still can't get the radio-buttons fixed.

**--EDIT 2--**
  Fixed the background for the radio-buttons using `setOpaque(false);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you mean by it "broke" the position of "yes" and "no" as a GridLayout should work just fine. I'd give it 1 column and 2 (or 0 for variable number of) rows via `new GridLayout(0, 1)`. Be sure that its opaque property is set as false by doing `radioPanel.setOpaque(false);`. This way it will show the background color of the container that it sits in. You may need to make the JRadioButtons non-opaque as well, I'm not sure.

Your btnPanel could use a BoxLayout and use Box.createGlue() to push the buttons over to the right side.

Most importantly -- if you haven't yet done so, please read the tutorials on use of the Swing layout managers which you can find [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html).

Comment: Sorry, I meant they are too stretched apart from each other vertically. And `radioPanel.setBackground(Color.darkGray);` has no effect any more.

Comment: 1) Despite GridLayout and setOpaque  I still get same problems (too stretched and different background). 2) I will check this method out right now. 3) These pages are open in my Internet browser 24/7.

Comment: @Hurdler: "too stretched" can be fixed by nesting the radioPanel into another JPanel acting as a container and perhaps using FlowLayout and then adding the container JPanel to the GUI. You have to play with your layouts and tweak things for them to work as you wish.

Comment: Ok, thanks. That's is more difficult than I thought it would be ;) Is there a way to set same background to the radio-buttons like on the screenshots?

Comment: @Hurdler: no, it's really not that difficult as all you're adding is one other containing JPanel. Again, to have any component use the same background as it's container call `myComponent.setOpaque(false);` on that component, as I thought I explained in my answer above.

Comment: Probably you are right, but I have never done anything gui-related, so I'm struggling (and that's why I decided to get some extra practise over the holidays). And yes, you explained it clearly, but I was calling setOpaque in the wrong place, now it looks good. The only thing to fix is just the position of "Yes" and "No". Thanks for your help.

Comment: Again, see my note on use of GridLayout above.

Answer (score 4):

A couple of things you can do about this.  You need to change your LayoutManager.  This is not a great task for BorderLayout.  You could do nested BoxLayouts.  A vertical box that has the vertical fixed height strut, label, vertical fixed height strut, yes radio, vertical fixed strut, no radio, Vertical glue, and the final button panel.  Then use your edit in the button panel to horizontally align them.  That's one option, but the nesting of the panels is annoying.

Another option go get TableLayout and learn how to use it.  TableLayout is one of the best LayoutManagers.  It's easy to use, solidly tested, and it makes Swing fun again.  You'll never use GridBagLayout ever ever ever again.

http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/tablelayout/

The final option is use the new GroupLayout.  I'm not terribly familiar with it, but it looks pretty easy.  And, it doesn't take as much code or nesting unnecessary panels like Box does.

Comment: Quick question, can I "merge" the cells in TableLayout?

Comment: You can have a component span several rows and/or columns.

Comment: Thanks, will use that one in the next window(s).